# JQuery DatePicker OnSelect load Image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Fairly new to asp.net Mvc and jquery.

Have the following code working fine, but I would like to load the image src every time the onSelect of the datepicker is fired. Any help much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
                onSelect: function(date,inst) {
                    alert(date)},                                       
                inline: true
            });
        });        
</script>

<h2>Select a date to view the diary:</h2>

<div id="datepicker">        
</div>

<div id ="diary">                                
    <img src="<%=Url.Action("Image", new { id = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") }) %>" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
   onSelect: function(date,inst) {
                    $('#diary img').attr('src', <new image path> );
      },                                       
   inline: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that nearly working but how do I pass the date to my action

$('#diary img').attr('src', '<%= Url.Action("Image", new (Id = date???) %>');

Comment: that depends more on ur business logic .....Please do remember to mark it useful if it was helpful  ....